# RegEx for creating paragraphs after every N chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long string (paragraph) with multiple sentences separated by dot.
I want to convert it to multiple paragraphs.
the rule is count from the beginning of string and find the first dot after 250th character and place a lineBreak after it. again count from this newly created lineBreak and find the first dot after 250th character and place a lineBreak after it and so on!

```
orginalString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu ius everti consequat instructior, sed modus vitae nostrud cu, ad. principes iracundia efficiendi pro. Et eam movet iudico ancillae. Ei mucius invidunt assueverit sit, nostrum oportere ne ius, qui similique scripserit heus et. Eam an tota mollis placerat, an quem voluptua appellantur est.Stet movet quaerendum his ea. Eum facete consequuntur ea, in vix liber quodsi. Percipit moderatius his et, id viderer salutandi vix. Scaevola suscipiantur id quo, ne eirmod consetetur cotidieque sit. Habemus noluisse ex ius.Cum ut dicant everti. Per ad vero exerci. Dolor eruditi eu eos. Alii fugit iisque sea ei, ponderum theophrastus concludaturque nec in. Eam ea modo dolores, has case pericula forensibus id.Laudem appetere senserit qui eu, pro ut essent euripidis. Vim ut elit utinam ridens, his facilis placerat eu. Mel omnis causae eripuit ei, mel no cibo essent temporibus, an quot efficiantur mea. Cu duo diam errem accommodare, nisl posse equidem an vis, his no omnes partem.'
```

and here is th final string:

```
finalString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu ius everti consequat instructior, sed modus vitae nostrud cu, ad. principes iracundia efficiendi pro. Et eam movet iudico ancillae. Ei mucius invidunt assueverit sit, nostrum oportere ne ius, qui similique scripserit heus et.
 Eam an tota mollis placerat, an quem voluptua appellantur est.Stet movet quaerendum his ea. Eum facete consequuntur ea, in vix liber quodsi. Percipit moderatius his et, id viderer salutandi vix. Scaevola suscipiantur id quo, ne eirmod consetetur cotidieque sit.
 Habemus noluisse ex ius.Cum ut dicant everti. Per ad vero exerci. Dolor eruditi eu eos. Alii fugit iisque sea ei, ponderum theophrastus concludaturque nec in. Eam ea modo dolores, has case pericula forensibus id.Laudem appetere senserit qui eu, pro ut essent euripidis.
 Vim ut elit utinam ridens, his facilis placerat eu. Mel omnis causae eripuit ei, mel no cibo essent temporibus, an quot efficiantur mea. Cu duo diam errem accommodare, nisl posse equidem an vis, his no omnes partem.'
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please try something before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex does the trick:

```js
originalString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu ius everti consequat instructior, sed modus vitae nostrud cu, ad. principes iracundia efficiendi pro. Et eam movet iudico ancillae. Ei mucius invidunt assueverit sit, nostrum oportere ne ius, qui similique scripserit heus et. Eam an tota mollis placerat, an quem voluptua appellantur est.Stet movet quaerendum his ea. Eum facete consequuntur ea, in vix liber quodsi. Percipit moderatius his et, id viderer salutandi vix. Scaevola suscipiantur id quo, ne eirmod consetetur cotidieque sit. Habemus noluisse ex ius.Cum ut dicant everti. Per ad vero exerci. Dolor eruditi eu eos. Alii fugit iisque sea ei, ponderum theophrastus concludaturque nec in. Eam ea modo dolores, has case pericula forensibus id.Laudem appetere senserit qui eu, pro ut essent euripidis. Vim ut elit utinam ridens, his facilis placerat eu. Mel omnis causae eripuit ei, mel no cibo essent temporibus, an quot efficiantur mea. Cu duo diam errem accommodare, nisl posse equidem an vis, his no omnes partem.';
// Regex pattern
// .{250} // 250 characters
// .*?\.  // followed by the shortest sequence of characters before a '.'
pattern = /(.{250}.*?\.)/g;
finalString = originalString.replace(pattern, "$1\n");
console.log(finalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we might be able to do that, however it may not work with certain dots such as `et.`, `etc.` and `i.e.`, which you might want to exclude those:

```
(((.+?){0,250})(\s)(.*?)([.\sA-Z]+?))
```

We have added a right boundary to check if this would be the end of sentence with higher probability:

```
([.\sA-Z]+?)
```

Capturing groups also helps to simply call the desired outputs.

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cpRrFS/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(((.+?){0,250})(\s)(.*?)([.\sA-Z]+?))/gm;
const str = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu ius everti consequat instructior, sed modus vitae nostrud cu, ad. principes iracundia efficiendi pro. Et eam movet iudico ancillae. Ei mucius invidunt assueverit sit, nostrum oportere ne ius, qui similique scripserit heus et. Eam an tota mollis placerat, an quem voluptua appellantur est.Stet movet quaerendum his ea. Eum facete consequuntur ea, in vix liber quodsi. Percipit moderatius his et, id viderer salutandi vix. Scaevola suscipiantur id quo, ne eirmod consetetur cotidieque sit. Habemus noluisse ex ius.Cum ut dicant everti. Per ad vero exerci. Dolor eruditi eu eos. Alii fugit iisque sea ei, ponderum theophrastus concludaturque nec in. Eam ea modo dolores, has case pericula forensibus id.Laudem appetere senserit qui eu, pro ut essent euripidis. Vim ut elit utinam ridens, his facilis placerat eu. Mel omnis causae eripuit ei, mel no cibo essent temporibus, an quot efficiantur mea. Cu duo diam errem accommodare, nisl posse equidem an vis, his no omnes partem.`;
const subst = `\n    $1\n\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get your match without using a capturing group and a non greedy quantifier using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

In the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) you can use `$&` to insert the matched substring followed by a newline `\n`

```
.{250}[^.]+\.
```

- `.{250}` Match any char except a newline 250 times
- `[^.]*` Match 0+ times not a dot (use `[^.\n]*` to also exclude matching a newline)
- `\.` Match a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GGSMGd/1)

```js
let orginalString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu ius everti consequat instructior, sed modus vitae nostrud cu, ad. principes iracundia efficiendi pro. Et eam movet iudico ancillae. Ei mucius invidunt assueverit sit, nostrum oportere ne ius, qui similique scripserit heus et. Eam an tota mollis placerat, an quem voluptua appellantur est.Stet movet quaerendum his ea. Eum facete consequuntur ea, in vix liber quodsi. Percipit moderatius his et, id viderer salutandi vix. Scaevola suscipiantur id quo, ne eirmod consetetur cotidieque sit. Habemus noluisse ex ius.Cum ut dicant everti. Per ad vero exerci. Dolor eruditi eu eos. Alii fugit iisque sea ei, ponderum theophrastus concludaturque nec in. Eam ea modo dolores, has case pericula forensibus id.Laudem appetere senserit qui eu, pro ut essent euripidis. Vim ut elit utinam ridens, his facilis placerat eu. Mel omnis causae eripuit ei, mel no cibo essent temporibus, an quot efficiantur mea. Cu duo diam errem accommodare, nisl posse equidem an vis, his no omnes partem.'
pattern = /.{250}[^.]+\./gm;
console.log(orginalString.replace(pattern, "$&\n"));
```

Answer (score -1):

finalString = orginalString.replace(/(.{250})(.*?)./g, '$1$2.\n')

Comment: Downvoted because it is unexplained and unproven. Will remove downvote if edited.